# Hibernate Envers Auditing

Tags: hibernate, auditing, nhibernate-4

I am using Hibernate4 with envers for audit logging purposes.

I have a table:

```
PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID(primaryKey),
         PRODUCT_CODE,
         PRODUCE_DESC,
         PRODUCT_FEE)
```

Hibernate has created an audit table `PRODUCTS_AUD`.

Whenever there is a change in the `Product` description, Hibernate is tracking the changes in the previous records.

Some records have only `Product_desc` changed. Some records have only `product_fees` changed for a particular `Product_id`. Is their a way to find out what all the changed fields are between revisions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us what you have tried, what results you expected and what results you received.

Answer (score 0):

Product audit table should log only the changes happens to the product table. So, table structure should be `PRODUCT_AUDIT(ID(Primary key),PRODUCT_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE)`.

Check whether is there any options to change audit table structure. Once you have table design like this, it is easy to find the what are changes happend.